# How can an instance of an object own another object of the same type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My user class has a property: `referring_user_id` which should point to another user. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
 user.first_name // => "Fred"
 user.referring_user.first_name // => "Steve"
```

What would the belongs_to look like in the User model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it would be like

```
class User
  belongs_to :referring_user, class_name: User
  ...
end
```

i also suggest you take a look at the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)